# Unbound Variable or Constructor error ML

Tags: constructor, ml

I am working with two function. One that takes a list, and the second that does some work on the list elements. The second function, multinHelp, is giving me the error

"stdIn:79.6-79.16 Error: unbound variable or constructor: multinHelp"

```
fun multin(L)=
let
 val a = hd(L)
 val b = hd(tl(L))
 val c = hd(tl(tl(L)))
in
 multinHelp([a,b,c])
end;
```

*---------------------------------------*

```
fun multinHelp([a,b,c])=
if c = 0 then [a]
else (b * hd(multinHelp([a,b,c])) :: multinHelp([a,b,c-1]);
```

I am not sure why I am receiving this error as I have set [a,b,c] in the first function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the second function *before* the first one to be able to use it from there.

Also, there is a closing parenthesis missing in the second function.